# Add dynamic content

Tags: django, forms, templates, tags

After a new article is posted (in a form via Ajax) on my Django news site, I want to return a link to the article.

To do so, I'm using a Template object that says:

```
if form.is_valid():
     form.instance.user = request.user
     new_article = form.save()
     success = Template('<div id="panel_input" class="col-lg-4"> <h2 class="text-center"> Success </h2> <p class="text-center"> Your Article has been posted. You can see and edit details by clicking <a href="{% url "article_manager:article" %}/{{ article_id }}">here</a>. </p></div>')
     context = Context({"article_id" : new_article.pk})
     return HttpResponse(success.render(context))
```

The urlsConf for this looks like:

```
...
 url(r'^article/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.article, name='article'),
...
```

The problem is that I get an error because of `{% url "article_manager:article" %}/{{ article_id }}`. Apparently, I must pass the `article_id` inside the previous tag, since the `urlsConf` requires the `id` parameter.

But I also get an **error** when I put the second tag inside the first, like this:

```
{% url "article_manager:article" {{ article_id }} %}
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this task, it doesn't seem to work with the tools I have. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `{% url "article_manager:article" article_id=article_id %}`

Maybe a little more explanation is needed: You were calling the template tag right `{% url "namespace:name" %}`. Remember that some templatetags can take arguments, in the `*args, **kwargs` form. The args can be any simple expression understood by the template language, *including a context variable* (no need to add double-braces). The kwargs follow the same rule, and have the form `argument=expression`. Thus, you can call some template tags with the form `{% tag "exp" 1 request number=5 username=user.name %}`

Comment: Now I'm getting the error `Could not parse the remainder: '=' from '='`

Comment: Never mind, the error was because I put a space on either side of the equals sign. Works now!